# How to create login with email from related table on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-ui

I have 2 tables with the names of users and admins.

**users**: id, username, password, admin_id

**admins**: id, email

I use login with laravel UI with default username from the users table. I want to do the login auth with username and email. The username is stored in the users table and the email is in the admins table

```
public function username()
{
    $login = request()->login;
    $field = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';
    if ($field == 'username') {
        User::where('username', $login)->first();
        request()->merge([$field => $login]);
        
        return $field;
    } else {
        User::whereHas('admin', function ($q) use ($login) {
            $q->where('email', $login);
        })->first();
        request()->merge([$field => $login]);
        
        return $field;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might wanna take a look at eloquent relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships. You'll also need a custom login function I think.

Comment: i have relation on model,,
can u help for logic when use laravel ui for login?

Comment: I don't know if this link is correct, but there are many tutorials on how to create a custom login function if you search on Google (for example: https://codingdriver.com/custom-login-register-forget-password-functionality-in-laravel-without-auth.html). Try to dive into it. For the next time you ask a question on here, try to show what you've already tried.